# Make enter key behave like tab key on form

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there an easy way to move around controls on a form exactly the same way as the tab key?  This includes moving around cells on a datagridview etc.

Comment: You need only to override the `ProcessCmdKey`, see [here for how](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-make-the-enter-key-behave-like-the-tab-key-in-a-datagrid-moving-to-the-next-cell.aspx ) and [here for why][2] [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/01/24/359334.aspx

Comment: @AZ That first link is dead, [here's an archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100615154507/http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-make-the-enter-key-behave-like-the-tab-key-in-a-datagrid-moving-to-the-next-cell.aspx) from the Internet Archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using winforms you should set the Form KeyPreview property to true

and in the keypress event for the form you should have

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
       GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true).Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the datagridview handles is own tab events for moving between the cells, you will have to create a custom datagrid control and override the onKeyUp event like so:

```
Public Class MyCustomDataGrid
    Inherits DataGridView

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyUp(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            e.Handled = True
            Me.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab)
        Else
            MyBase.OnKeyUp(e)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

That will process the enter key as a tab key when trying to tab though the datagrid cells,
if you need to handle tab also on the form you will have to do what Marioh said, but with a little change.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyUp(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter AndAlso Not ActiveControl.GetType() Is GetType(Class1) Then
            e.Handled = True
            Me.ProcessTabKey(Not e.Shift)
        Else
            MyBase.OnKeyUp(e)
        End If
    End Sub
```

You will just have to add a check for type of the active control otherwise the form will stop your custom datagrid tab code from working.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
Keys keyPressed = (Keys)msg.WParam.ToInt32();
switch (keyPressed)
{
    case Keys.Enter:
    case Keys.Tab:
        Control ctrl = this.GetNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true);
        while (ctrl is TextBox == false) 
        {
            ctrl = this.GetNextControl(ctrl, true);
        }
        ctrl.Focus();
        return true;
    default:
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
}
```